# How can I recover the private key for my bitcoin address?

Tags: private-key, lost-bitcoins, wallet-recovery

I want to make withdrawal from my Bitcoin address to which I just transferred some bitcoins. The address has changed after I made a transactions to the first address. But it was requesting the private key to create the payment. How can i get the private key to spend fund from the address?

Comment: What software are you using? Was the first address created in the same software? Where is the private key being requested?

Comment: I think you misunderstand something. A single wallet file can have many addresses. Your address didn't "change"; the wallet does not have a single address or anything.

Comment: I've downvoted this question, because the asker has not returned to provide the requested additional information and as it is, only a very basic answer can be given to the question which is unlikely to be interesting to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Private keys cannot be recovered. If you lose or forget the private key, the bitcoins become unspendable.

Comment: not true... I lost 15 bitcoin privates and I paid a service online to recover my private keys.
I did not have them in a virtual wallet. I had them on a usb. One Usb with public and one usb with private.
Service cost 20%. Rather have 80% of something!

Comment: @marlin "I paid a service online to recover my private keys" - You must be very delusional.